# 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.' is seen after deploying ReactJS app to Azure through VS Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I have a React app on Visual Studio code which is referencing the Azure web app of my Asp.Net MVC (Web Api) application. The MVC application is a .NET Framework 4.7 project on Visual Studio 2017.

In simple words, My react app on visual studio code is consuming the azure web which was published successfully from my visual studio 2017 project. This React app works good on local host and is able to GET/POST details by accessing the azure web app.

In order to host this React app as an azure web app, I deployed it to a new azure web app through azure extensions from visual studio code (This was done in the same resource group where the mvc web app exist). But after the react app got deployed, I could'nt see any thing on my browser except the message - 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page'.

Please Note, In my react app, there was no web.config. I referenced this article (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-reactjs-with-axios-using-web-api-and-sql-server/) to build the react app.

I would like to know - What is missing here ? Am I doing anything wrong with the deployment ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the Kudu console, either through the portal or mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net and see what content is inside `./site/wwwroot`? That's where App Services will be looking for your base html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i did to solve my problem:

1. Created the production build by executing 'npm run build' command. A build folder got generated in the solution with some meta data files.
2. Referenced the build folder while deploying the react app to azure.

References used:
https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321